# How to cache properly using dynamic rendering?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, caching, next.js13, react-cache

I’m using next 13 and I have a page that’s being generated in each request because of some data for specific users.

A big part of the used data is the same for everyone, so I tried to cache it. But I noticed something that I wasn’t expecting: fetch cache works in that scenario, but `cache` function doesn’t. I created the cached version out of the component and used primitive values as parameters. Even using same data, the function is still called.

I thought of creating an api endpoint for that, since fetch cache works, but not sure if it’s a good practice since that code runs on server (I shouldn’t need to call next api from server).